# UI-GRID Expandable Grid. Programatically expand one row

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I want to hide the + icon in the far left column and add another icon.

When the user clicks the new Icon I want to programatically expand that specific row.

I see there is gridApi.expandable.expandAllRows();

Is there a way to expand just one row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to change the default plus icon to a different icon, you can simply override the template for the expandableRowHeader.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/expandableRowHeader',
    "<div class=\"ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell\"><div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\"><i ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared' : !row.isExpanded, 'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared' : row.isExpanded }\" ng-click=\"grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)\"></i></div></div>"
  );
```

You can change the **`ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared' : !row.isExpanded, 'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared' : row.isExpanded }\"`** and change them to a different icon of your choice.

Comment: Can I remove the + sign from the left column, and add my own icon to a different column?

Comment: What do you mean by different column. A new row header different from the plus sign column.

Comment: Your solution worked.. I added my own plus icon to a different column and invoked your api.  Thanks

Comment: Kathir, how do I remove the Expandable column completely?  I now have my own icon working and don't want the column for the built in expansion.

Comment: @Kathir What is $templateCache and where we should add $templateCache.put ? Any plnkr or example of it?

Comment: @Kathir. I am using '+' sign to expand row but 'expandableRow' is not set for parent grid until page is reloaded. See my question at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042217/how-to-set-expandeblerow-property-to-ui-grid

Answer (score 5):

You can use toggleRowExpansion function, add this attribute to the desired element which will be trigger this toggle:

`ng-click="grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)"`

Comment: how do we put this on the particular row, if ui-grid is generating the rows/cells? I want to click a row to expand and collapse it.