# UI-GRID Expandable Grid. Programatically expand one row on click of row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

1. I don't want to use the default, `+` icon, to expand the row.
2. Clicking anywhere on the row should expand it.

I tried this:

**HTML**

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-expandable class="grid">
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngTouch','ui.grid', 'ui.grid.expandable',
          'ui.grid.selection','ui.grid.pagination','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$compile','$scope', '$http', '$log', 
  function ($compile,$scope, $http, $log) {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar:0,
      expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
      expandableRowHeight: 150,
      expandableRowScope: {
      subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable'
    },

    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },

    rowTemplate: '<div ng-click="grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)" ng-style="{ \’cursor\’: row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>'
  }
}]);
```

Note: When I use `rowTemplate`, nothing is displayed. However, when it's removed, the rows aren't clickable.

Comment: rowTemplate: '<div ng-     click="grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)" ng-style="{ \’cursor\’: row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}"><div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div><div ng-cell></div></div>'

Answer (score 0):

You can try by overriding the template for the `expandableRowHeader`.

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/expandableRowHeader',
  "<div class=\"ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-expandable-buttons-cell\" ng-click=\"grid.api.expandable.toggleRowExpansion(row.entity)\"><div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\"><i ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-plus-squared' : !row.isExpanded, 'ui-grid-icon-minus-squared' : row.isExpanded }\"></i></div></div>"
);
```

This should work since the click event is now on the row instead of the icon (the 'i' tag).

This is a modification of the answer at [UI-GRID Expandable Grid. Programatically expand one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629189/ui-grid-expandable-grid-programatically-expand-one-row) (different requirement there).